# How write log files with .NET 8 container images?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, .net-8.0

We migrated all production images to .NET 8 and, as explained by [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/containers/8.0/app-user), now the default root-less user is `app` for safety reasons.
In fact now Visual Studio automatically generates `Dockerfile` including the new `USER app` line.

```yaml
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:8.0-alpine AS base
USER app
WORKDIR /app
```

By default all our production containers write their logs using Serilog in the host OS at `/var/log/**specific_folder**` thanks to volume mapping.

```yaml
version: '3.9'

services:

  historical-updater-indexes:
    image: historical-updater:latest
    container_name: historical-updater-indexes
    restart: no
    volumes:
      - /home/user/docker/historical-updater/appsettings_indexes.json:/app/appsettings.json
      - /var/log/historical-updater-indexes:/app/logs
    env_file:
      - common.env
```

Now this mapping doesn't work anymore because the root-less user `app` cannot access this folder that by default is root a folder.

Which is the right way to manage this situation without coming back to `root` user inside the container?

Comment: Map the folder that `app` user has access to?

Comment: Can you write logs to stdout, instead of a file?

Comment: Yes, maybe but I need log persistence on disk after container recreation.

Answer (score 0):

You can give the app user access to write to `/var/log` on the host.

On a Ubuntu machine I have access to, the group owner of `/var/log` is the `syslog` group.

The UID of the app user in the ASP.NET container is 1654.

To give it access on the host, you need to create a user on the host with UID 1654 and then add it to the `syslog` group.

You can use the following commands to create a user and add it to the syslog group

```
sudo useradd -r -s /bin/false -u 1654 docker-aspnet
sudo usermod -aG syslog docker-aspnet
```

I've called the user `docker-aspnet` on the host. You can choose any name you like. When the access rights are checked, it's the uid of the user that's checked and not the name. So it's important the user has uid 1654.

Now, when your container writes to `/var/log`, the system will see that uid 1654 is in group `syslog` and that group `syslog` has write access to the directory.

As for why it has to be UID 1654, Microsoft have chosen that number and set it in their image here: https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/main/src/runtime-deps/8.0/bookworm-slim/amd64/Dockerfile

Comment: As far as I understand you should not add new user, just give rights to the app one.

Comment: The app user doesn't exist on the host where the access rights are checked

Comment: If user does not exists how the `USER app` would work?

Comment: Because that's inside the container and the user exists there

Comment: But you need to setup user rights inside that container to make everything work, no?

Comment: Yes, you need to do that too. But that works as it should. OP's problem is writing to a directory on the host that's mapped into the container using a bind mount.